# Deserialise JSON to Dictionary<string, string >

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

I’m sure there will be a barrage of stupid questions from me as I migrate away from the extremely loose PHP to F#.

This one should hopefully be straightforward.
I have a json file

```
{
“some_ key” : “some_value”
}
```

That will have a list of a few hundred items in a simple key,value (string,string) format.

In F# I’d like to decode that string into a `dictionary<string, string>` .
Seems obvious enough but all suggestions I’ve seen seem extremely verbose so assume I’m missing something simple.

I have Thoth and FSharp.Data at my disposal, though open to anything else free.

Comment: Why a loose Dictionary when you have FSharp.Data's JSON Type provider and parser?

Comment: Unfamiliarity. I am more than open to using a different type, but in this case the json is a literal dictionary - a list of words and definitions - so seemed more semantic in my mind.

Comment: And another reason I need to be able to dynamically access the properties. E.g call them by a function argument which I can't seem to do on the JSON type provider.

Comment: And furthermore it can't seem to dynamically load a sample file. I have no control over the JSON, it's a user-provided file and it might not be the exact structure as the sample file (it should be, but user error etc. I need to be able to handle missing or extra keys). If I could load the sample file as a provided file that would solve that problem, but can't seem to do that.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?  Different versions of .Net have different JSON serializers built-in.  Or you can use the (free) [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) [tag:json.net] in all versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure .NET Core example if you are only after something simple:

```ml
let json = """{
  "some_ key" : "some_value"
}"""

let data = 
    System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(json)
        .RootElement
        .EnumerateObject()
    |> Seq.map (fun o -> o.Name, o.Value.GetString())
    |> dict
```

Answer (score 2):

An out-of-the-box .NET solution could look like:

```ml
open System.Text.Json
open System.Collections.Generic

let json = """{
    "key": "value",
    "foo": "bar"
}"""

let dic: IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> =
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json);


// Usage example
dic.["foo"] = "bar" // true

let someKey = "dimdi"
match dic.TryGetValue someKey with
| false, _ -> printfn "Missing key %s" someKey
| _, v -> printfn "Found %s" v
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Thoth the magic method is Decode.keyValuePairs.

```
open Thoth.Json.Net

let json = """{
“some_ key” : “some_value”
}"""

let decoder : Decoder<(string * string) list> = Decode.keyValuePairs Decode.string 
Decode.fromString decoder json |> Result.map dict 

// Ok System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>
```

Comment: A convincing argument to go back to PHP or Javascript  
How do I access the values? 
```let decoder : Decoder<(string * string) list> = Decode.keyValuePairs Decode.string

let arr = Decode.fromString decoder json |> Result.map dict

arr.["some_key"]```

Gives me a "cannot apply indexing to an expression"

Comment: Errorhandling is bigger question than this. You can unwrap the type and throw an error. Read this https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Comment: Unwrap : let unwrap = function | Ok v -> v | Error e -> failwithf "%O" e

Comment: It is the arr.["some_key"] that fails in the IDE so can't build. The actual decode code seems to work fine (though inferred type is `Result<IDictionary<string,string>,string>`

I'm still learning ASP.NET and F# so my debugging skills are not good and was not expecting a json decode to provide any problems, but it seems the "system" I'm "porting" just really relies on dynamic typing so F# is probably the wrong tool for the job. I will sleep on it and ask the question again in more detail as I'm having more and more issues the further I delve into both FSharp.Data and Thoth.

Comment: It is a different way of thinking for sure

Comment: A different language gives a different way to think about problems, some solutions that are common in one language are approached in a different way in another. Being aware of these differences makes you a better developer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FSharp.Data and the Json provider is not an option, you can use [Fleece](https://github.com/fsprojects/Fleece) instead of Thoth, which works perfectly with FSharp.Data

```
#r "nuget: Fleece.FSharpData"

open System.Collections.Generic
open Fleece.FSharpData

let (x: Result<Dictionary<string,string>, _>) = parseJson """{"some_ key" : "some_value"}"""

(* 
val x : Result<Dictionary<string,string>,Fleece.FSharpData.DecodeError> =
  Ok dict [("some_ key", "some_value")]
*)
```

The function `parseJson` will work with text, but if you have your json already parsed with FSharp.Data you can use `ofJson` instead.