# Deserialize JSON without knowing full structure

Tags: json, .net, f#, f#-data

I'm redoing the backend of a *very* basic framework that connects to a completely customizable frontend. It was originally in PHP but for the refactor have been plodding away in F#. Although it seems like PHP might be the more suited language. But people keep telling me you can do everything in F# and I like the syntax and need to learn and this seemingly simple project has me stumped when it comes to JSON. This is a further fleshed out version of my [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868918/deserialise-json-to-dictionarystring-string/66874933#66874933), but it got alot more complex than I thought.

Here goes.

The frontend is basically a collection of HTML files, which are simply loaded in PHP and preg_replace() is used to replace things like [var: varName] or [var: array|key] or the troublesome one: `[lang: hello]`. That needs to be replaced by a variable defined in a translation dictionary, which is stored as JSON which is also editable by a non-programmer.

**I can't change the frontend or the JSON files**, and both are designed to be edited by non-programmers so it is very likely that there will be errors, calls to language variables that don't exist etc.

So we might have 2 json files, `english.json` and `french.json`

english.json contains:

```
{
   "hello":"Hello",
   "bye":"Goodbye"
}
```

french.json:

```
{
"hello": "Bonjour",
"duck": "Canard"
//Plus users can add whatever else they want here and expect to be able to use it in a template
}
```

There is a template that contains

```
<b>[lang: hello]</b>

<span>Favourite Animal: [lang:duck]</span>
```

In this case, if the language is set to "english" and english.json is being loaded, that should read:

```
<b>Hello</b>

<span>Favourite Animal: </span>

Or in French:

<b>Bonjour</b>

<span>Favourite Animal: Canard</span>
```

We can assume that the json format `key: value` is always `string:string` but ideally I'd like to handle `string: 'T`  as well but that might be beyond the scope of this question.

So I need to convert a JSON file (called by dynamic name, which gave F# Data a bit of an issue I couldn't solve last night as it only allowed a static filename as a sample, and since these two files have potential to be different from sample and provided, the type provider doesn't work) to a dictionary or some other collection.

Now inside the template parsing function I need to replace `[lang: hello]` with something like

```
let key = "duck"

(*Magic function to convert JSON to usable collection*)

let languageString = convertedJSONCollection.[key] (*And obviously check if containsKey first*)
```

Which means I need to call the key dynamically, and I couldn't figure out how to do that with the type that FSharp.Data provided.

I have played around with some Thoth as well to some promising results that ended up going nowhere. I avoided JSON.NET because I thought it was paid, but just realised I am mistaken there so might be an avenue to explore

For comparison, the PHP function looks something like this:

```
function loadLanguage($lang='english){
    $json = file_get_contents("$lang.json");
    return json_decode($json, true);
}

$key = 'duck';

$langVars = loadLanguage();
$duck = $langVars[$key] || "";
```

Is there a clean way to do this in F#/.NET? JSON seems really painful to work with in comparison to PHP/Javascript and I'm starting to lose my mind. Am I going to have to write my own parser (which means probably going back to PHP)?

Cheers to all you F# geniuses who know the answer :p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialise JSON to Dictionary<string, string >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868918/deserialise-json-to-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: This question is (in a large part) a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868918/deserialise-json-to-dictionarystring-string Additional aspects should be separate questions.

Comment: That question was mine (and linked in this question ). I had trouble with the responses of that as some didn’t directly apply to my situation (dynamic loading and accessing) which seemed to render the ones I tested unusable. Perhaps it should’ve been broken into smaller questions though!

Comment: Yes, please break it down. SO is not a great place for „how do I replace a (part of an) application.“ Once you start looking for „how do I read a file“, „how do I parse the file contents as JSON“... you‘ll find the answers much more easily.

Comment: You're right, it jus tfeels like spam if I'm asking alot of small questions in a short space. But you are correct. I will make sure to do that going forward

Comment: Also, instead of asking new questions it’s considered polite to clarify open points (regarding the original question) and eventually accept an answer. Asking (almost identical) new ones won‘t help (usually).

Comment: if you break it down you might find that most questions have an answer already :-) and if they don’t: asking many useful questions is not considered spam.

Comment: Appreciate the words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open Thoth.Json.Net
let deserialiseDictionary (s: string) =
    s
    |> Decode.unsafeFromString (Decode.keyValuePairs Decode.string)
    |> Map.ofList

let printDictionary json =
    json
    |> deserialiseDictionary
    |> fun m -> printfn "%s" m.["hello"] // Hello
```

For the question about 'T the question becomes, what can 'T be? For json it very limited, it can be a number of things, string, json-object, number, bool or json array. What should happen if it is bool or a number?

Comment: T would be bool or int converted to string, it would never be an array. If that Thoth one works then I was massively over complicating it. Thanks